# What does a 'reset' refer to with Drupal?

Tags: 8, configuration

In the [docs for the State API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview), the term 'reset' is used, without any reference as to what a reset is:

> use State API to store transient information, that is okay to lose
>   after a reset.

I've spent a significant amount of time digging through the back-end implementation of the State API, looking at the database tables, and testing writing values, and as far as I can tell, the state data is never removed. So I'm thinking that by a 'reset', they mean wiping the entire DB, re-installing Drupal, then importing all the config.

I'm just looking for other confirmation before I update the doc page with a clearer explanation. Can anyone confirm that my theory on what a 'reset' is, is correct? And if it's not, can anyone explain what a 'reset' is?

Comment: state is instance-specific(like last cron run time), config is site-specific(like system mail) / permanent. Reset means that if you delete all state, nothing breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate you taking the time, but I'm still not clear on what a 'reset' is. I've never seen this term used in reference to Drupal before this.

Comment: that documentation is bogus, there is no reset and it is never OK to delete state information, it is also not done :) Please create a bug report

Comment: @Berdir: "never OK to delete state information" - what use case is there that would cause site to break if state would got flushed?

Comment: @Jaypan: do you even understand what state is in this context?

Comment: Ivan - Regarding your reply to berdir, I'm not concerned with a 'flush' of the state, what I'm trying to determine is what a 'reset' of a Drupal system is. And 'state' is the State API, which is a system for permanent instance-specific configuration (not to be confused with the Configuration API).

Comment: Berdir - thanks. I opened a ticket here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2909896